# Magento CatalogSearch to use OR instead of AND

Tags: magento

I have a custom catalog search that has multiple fields to search by (eg: width, length, etc).   But by default, Magento is doing it as an AND search. I want it to be an OR search.

Is this a setting? I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You've just found the Magento trick to increase the amount of returns from its **LIKE** search. Changing it to **OR** logic doesn't make it much better. More results, even less relevance.

You're better off using Lucene, Sphinx or Solr for your search indexer. There are modules for the first two, the last is a function of the web server.

Tilting at the windmills of Magento search to change **AND** to **OR** requires a class overwrite for

`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php`

in

`public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)`

```
if ($like) {
     $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
}
```

needs to be

```
if ($like) {
     $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
}
```

Just keep in mind that everyone was asking to do the reverse when Magento decided to release later versions with **OR** logic.

Good search begins with Lucene which is built into the Zend Framework that Magento is based on and goes up from there. It's nice having stemming, plurality and fuzzy search that allows minor misspellings. And really importantly, the relevance rating actually is generated so that the sort by relevance **actually works<sup>TM</sup>**

Magento **LIKE** search has no relevance, the returns are arbitrary, often in database order so adding more returns just means your customer often has to sort through 10-30 pages to find anything.